# PHP. Heredoc документ

Tags: php

Heredoc документ, делаю как в книге. Вроде код без ошибок, но тут выдает такое.

**Код:**

```
<?php

if ('POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
    print 'Hello, ' . $_POST['my_name'];
} else {
    print <<<_HTML_
    <form method="post" action="$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]">
        Your name: <input type="text" name="my_name">
            <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Say Hello">
    </form>
    _HTML_;
}
```

**Ошибка:**

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in 
D:\Soft\OSPanel\domains\new.loc\www\form.php on line 13
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите версию PHP у себя. Для PHP < 7.3  раньше было ограничение:

> строка с закрывающим идентификатором не должна содержать других
> символов, за исключением точки с запятой (;). Это означает, что
> идентификатор не должен вводиться с отступом и что не может быть
> никаких пробелов или знаков табуляции до или после точки с запятой.
> Важно также понимать, что первым символом перед закрывающим
> идентификатором должен быть символ новой строки, определённый в вашей
> операционной системе. Например, в UNIX системах, включая macOS, это
> \n. После закрывающего идентификатора также сразу должна начинаться
> новая строка.
>
> Если это правило нарушено и закрывающий идентификатор не является
> "чистым", считается, что закрывающий идентификатор отсутствует и PHP
> продолжит его поиск дальше. Если в этом случае верный закрывающий
> идентификатор так и не будет найден, то это вызовет ошибку парсинга с
> номером строки в конце скрипта.

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

а вот в 7.3

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/migration73.new-features.php#migration73.new-features.core.heredoc

> Более гибкий синтаксис Heredoc и Nowdoc
>
> После закрывающего идентификатора в doc-строках больше не нужно
> ставить точку с запятой или новую строку. Кроме того, закрывающий
> идентификатор может быть с отступом, и в этом случае он будет удалён
> из всех строк в doc-строке.